# Amortized performance of LinkedList vs HashMap

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, computer-science

The amortised performance of Hash tables is often said to be O(1) for most operations.

What is the amortized performance for a search operation on say a standard LinkedList implementation? Is it O(n)?

I'm a little confused on how this is computed, since in the worst-case (assuming say a hash function that always collides), a Hash table is pretty much equivalent to a LinkedList in terms of say a search operation (assuming a standard bucket implementation).

I know in practise this would never happen unless the hash function was broken, and so the average performance is almost constant time over a series of operations since collisions are rare. But when calculating amortized worst-case performance, shouldn't we consider the worst-case sequence with the worst-case implementation?

Comment: I know they're not. But if I implement my own hash table class and use a hash function that always returns, say 1, for every key, then it basically degrades to a LinkedList (assuming I used lists for buckets). In reality this is stupid, but perhaps there may be a set of values that has a high-rate of collisions for a particular hash function implementation. Does this get considered when calculating amortised cost? Or do we just assume no collisions (or very infrequent).

Comment: You don't assume *very* infrequent collisions, you'd generally assume a collision rate of (1/bucket_count) between two keys. But in any kind of serious work you would state this assumption -- tables that just say "hashtables are O(1)" without qualification are over-simplifying the situation. They just happen to be accurate for pretty much all practical uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as "amortized worst-case performance". Amortized performance is a kind of "average" performance over a long sequence of operations.

With a hash table, sometimes the hash table will need to be resized after a long sequence of inserts, which will take O(n) time. But, since it only happens every O(n) inserts, that operation's cost is spread out over all the inserts to get O(1) amortized time.

Yes, a hash table could be O(n) for every operation in the worst case of a broken hash function. But, analyzing such a hash table is meaningless because it won't be the case for typical usage.

Comment: So it's an average performance assuming a low rate of hash collisions? I thought there was no probability or assumptions in calculating amortised cost.

Comment: Actually, there are probabilities, and there are assumptions. That's what is meant by "average" -- the average is over an implied set of possibilities, of which the "worst case" is just one.

Comment: @kufudo: you treat incoming keys as random variables evenly distributed in a range, so you can compute (say) the mean number of elements put in a slot. It's a very well-defined concept.

Answer (score 2):

"Worst case" sometimes depends on "worst case under what constraints".

The case of a hashtable with a valid but stupid hash function mapping all keys to 0 generally isn't a meaningful "worst case", it's not sufficiently interesting. So you can analyse a hashtable's average performance under the minimal assumption that (for practical purposes) the hash function distributes the set of all keys uniformly across the set of all hash values.

If the hash function is reasonably sound but not cryptographically secure there's a separate "worst case" to consider. A malicious or unwitting user could systematically provide data whose hashes collide. You'd come up with a different answer for the "worst case input" vs the "worst case assuming input with well-distributed hashes".

In a given sequence of insertions to a hashtable, one of them might provoke a rehash. Then you would consider that one the "worst case" in that particular. This has very little to do with the input data overall -- if the load factor gets high enough you're going to rehash *eventually* but *rarely*. That's why the "amortised" running time is an interesting measure, whenever you can put a tighter upper bound on the total cost of `n` operations than just `n` times the tightest upper bound on one operation.

Even if the hash function is cryptographically secure, there is a negligible probability that you could get input whose hashes all collide. This is where there's a difference between "averaging over all possible inputs" and "averaging over a sequence of operations with worst-case input". So the word "amortised" also comes with small print. In my experience it normally means the average over a series of operations, and the issue of whether the data is a good or a bad case is *not* part of the amortisation. nneonneo says that "there's no such thing as amortized worst-case performance", but in my experience there certainly is such a thing as worst-case amortised performance. So it's worth being precise, since this might reflect a difference in what we each expect the term to mean.

When hashtables come up with `O(1)` amortized insertion, they mean that `n` insertions takes `O(n)` time, either (a) assuming that nothing pathologically bad happens with the hash function or (b) expected time for `n` insertions assuming random input. Because you get the same answer for hashtables either way, it's tempting to be lazy about saying which one you're talking about.

Comment: I think this causes more confusion than clarification. Usually "worst case" is just the worst situation you can think of, while "average" means you're taking the expectation of a random variable which models your running time, period.

Comment: @akappa: most of the time, but the questioner is specifically asking about amortised running time, and actually it's quite common for "amortised" to mean neither of those two things, it's the average of something else. I think a discussion of this is warranted, and it's not all *that* unusual to consider something other than the two things you mention. YMMV.